# How to print password combination (but with custom constraints for each index)

Tags: python, string, loops, passwords, combinations

I am trying to build a dynamic password recovery tool. You can specify a password, and an unknown character list which correspond to unknown password indexes. So, if you remember 90% of your password, and can't remember a few letters, this will do a light weight brute force for you.
I am able to combine the user supplied password with an unknown character list; however, I am stuck trying to print every potential password.

I am stuck here:

```
password = 'Dude123'
charList = ['d8','vV','','D8','','','']
finalString = [''.join(set((a, b))) for a, b in zip(password, charList)] 

print(finalString) #This statement yields the following
['Dd8', 'uv^', 'd', 'eD8', '1', '2', '3']
```

Now I need to print:
Dude123
dude123
8ude123
Dvde123
dvde123
8vde123
...

or something to that effect (it doesn't have loop through the characters in any particular order, I just need a list of all the possible combinations.

Thank you for any help!

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> password = 'Dude123' 
>>> charList = ['d8','vV','','D8','','',''] 
>>> 
>>> finalString = [''.join(set((a, b))) for a, b in zip(password, charList)] 
>>> 
>>> possibles = list(''.join(poss) for poss in itertools.product(*finalString))
>>> possibles
['Dude123', 'DudD123', 'Dud8123', 'Dvde123', 'DvdD123', 'Dvd8123', 'DVde123', 'DVdD123', 'DVd8123', 'dude123', 'dudD123', 'dud8123', 'dvde123', 'dvdD123', 'dvd8123', 'dVde123', 'dVdD123', 'dVd8123', '8ude123', '8udD123', '8ud8123', '8vde123', '8vdD123', '8vd8123', '8Vde123', '8VdD123', '8Vd8123']
```

Comment: YES! That is exactly what I needed! How does your thought process arrive at these sorts of elegant solutions? I have been thinking of a solution to this problem for a week, and I felt like I was just staring into a black hole or something. (I am accepting your answer, but it says that I need to wait 8 minutes)

Comment: This is a pretty common programming task (just look at the "related" list on the right), and so this one wasn't thought so much as memory.  The itertools module is pretty awesome, and it's definitely worth your time to read through the examples in the docs.  It can take a while to pick up this way of thinking, but since you're already comfortable with zip you're half the way there!