# Generate all possible passwords based on character mapping -- possible in 3 lines of python?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, permutation

I came across this interview question on this page: (http://newworld-alex.blogspot.com/2009/03/facebook-interviewzz.html)

> Technical question: In python, given a dictionary of character variations for some word, *e.g. dictChars = {"e" : [E, 3], "x" : [X], "a" : [A, @], "m" : [M]}* implement a password-cracker-like partial string permutation generator, i.e. produce *exaM, exAm, exAM, ex@m, ...*. I implemented a simple 3-line recursive solution in Python.

I have a solution in Python, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it 3 lines like he did.

Just FYI, here is my current solution:

```
def allPossiblePasswords(password, mapping):
   if len(password) == 0:
      return [""]
   else:
      next = allPossiblePasswords(password[1:], mapping)
      if password[0] in mapping:
         return [c + n for c in mapping[password[0]] for n in next]
      else:
         return [password[0] + n for n in next]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[Self-plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234395/how-to-print-password-combination-but-with-custom-constraints-for-each-index/6234417#6234417) doesn't count, right?

```
import itertools

def all_possibles(password, mapping):
    char_options = ([char]+mapping.get(char,[]) for char in password)
    for poss in itertools.product(*char_options):
        yield ''.join(poss)
```

which can be made as compact as you like, even a one-line variant:

```
possibles = lambda p,m: map(''.join, itertools.product(*([c]+m.get(c,[]) for c in p)))
```

Edit: Ah.  I hadn't noticed that recursion was a requirement.  In that case, how about:

```
def all_recur(password, mapping):
    return [''] if not password else [c + n for c in [password[0]] + mapping.get(password[0], []) for n in all_recur(password[1:], mapping)]
```

which is basically just a compressed version of yours.  Note that both of these also return 'exam' (i.e. the unmodified password); I'm not sure if that was wanted or not.

Comment: I thought of using `product` too, but isn't the OP asking for a _recursive_ solution?

Comment: I always feel like programming challenges like "do task X in N lines or less" should have an additional condition like "lines must be 80 characters or less".

Comment: @Li-aungYip: that probably makes sense (and is trivially done here by splitting into two lines and shortening the names).  But "in N lines or less" contests are only interesting IMHO if they show a new idiom anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
mapping = {'a': ['A', '@'], 'x': ['X'], 'e': ['E', 3], 'm': ['M']}

password = "exam"

from itertools import product
allPossible = list(product(*([letter] + mapping[letter] for letter in password)))
```

Comment: You need to wrap the `product` call in a list comprehension or `map` using `''.join`, since it will return the products as a generator of tuples of characters.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I just assumed a generator would suffice. Anyways, edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in so many ways. But I'm posting it anyway. It's a recursive solution, as requested.

```
>>> def pw_vars(in_word, out_word, equivs):
...     if not in_word: return [out_word]
...     return sum((pw_vars(in_word[1:], out_word + c, equivs) for c in [in_word[0]] + equivs[in_word[0]]), [])
... 
>>> pw_vars('foo', '', {'f':['F', '='], 'o':['0', 'O']})
['foo', 'fo0', 'foO', 'f0o', 'f00', 'f0O', 'fOo', 'fO0', 'fOO', 'Foo', 'Fo0', 
 'FoO', 'F0o', 'F00', 'F0O', 'FOo', 'FO0', 'FOO', '=oo', '=o0', '=oO', '=0o', 
 '=00', '=0O', '=Oo', '=O0', '=OO']
```

I hope I don't have to say that you should never actually do this. Did the person actually get this job? I'm skeptical.

Actually though I've realized that DSM's version is better -- almost tolerable! Here's my version of DSM's version, for what it's worth (not so much). This one satisfies Mark Ransom's point below too.

```
>>> def pw_vars(pw, equivs):
...     if not pw: return ('',)
...     return (c + var for c in [pw[0]] + equivs.get(pw[0]) for var in pw_vars(pw[1:], equivs))
... 
>>> list(pw_vars('foo', {'f':['F', '='], 'o':['0', 'O']}))
['foo', 'fo0', 'foO', 'f0o', 'f00', 'f0O', 'fOo', 'fO0', 'fOO', 'Foo', 'Fo0', 'FoO', 'F0o', 'F00', 'F0O', 'FOo', 'FO0', 'FOO', '=oo', '=o0', '=oO', '=0o', '=00', '=0O', '=Oo', '=O0', '=OO']
```

Comment: Nice code, but doesn't work if there's a letter that's not in the map.

Comment: @MarkRansom, are you sure it's nice code? :) You're right -- I didn't bother with corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
equivs = dict(e=['E', '3'], x=['X'], a=['A', '@'], m=['M'])

def gen(c, *cs):
    if cs: return (x + y for x in [c] + equivs.get(c, []) for y in gen(*cs))
    else: return [c] + equivs.get(c, [])

for each in gen(*'erxuam'):
    print each
```